# modify the name of the log files to include jobid

Tags: python, snakemake

I am trying to include the rule name, the wild card, and the external job id into my log file name for a pipeline to make the debugging process smoother (for example: `snakejob.<rulename>.<wildcard>.e<jobid>`). I couldn't find a way to incorporate the rule name or the job id. The default log file name include job id so I think there must be a way to do it.
here is an example of rule that I have in my snakefile:

```
rule index_input:
    input:
        vcf = "{region}/example.vcf"
    output: "{region}/example.vcf.tbi"
    resources:
        mem = 2,
    threads:1,
    log:
        logo = "log/{region}.o",
        loge = "log/{region}.e",
    shell:
        """
        tabix {input.vcf}
        """
```

here is an example of my execution file:

```
snakemake --ri \
        -s $SNAKEFILE \
        --drmaa " -l h_rt=24:00:00  \
                -l mfree={resources.mem}G \
                -l gpfsstate=0 \
                -pe serial {threads} \
                -V -cwd \
                -o {log.logo} \
                -e {log.loge} \
                -S /bin/bash" \
        --jobs $JOBNUM \
        --latency-wait $WAITTIME \
        --restart-times $RETRY \
        $1 $2
```

is there any way i can do something like this in my snakefile

```
log:
        logo = "log/{rulename}{region}.o{jobid}"
```

or something like this in execution file"

```
-o {jobname}{log.logo}.o{jobid}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think to include the rule name you can use the wildcard `{rule}`. For a specific wildcard you could use the `params` directive. For example:

```
rule one:
    input:
        ...
    output:
        '{region}.txt',
    params:
        jobname= '{region}',
    shell:
        ...
```

Then execute as:

```
snakemake --cluster "qsub -o log/{rule}.{params.jobname}.o{jobid}"
```

Of course every rule whose jobs are submitted to the cluster must contain `jobname` as an item of `params`.

(Not tested)

Comment: I have not tested this with ```--cluster``` potion. But when I use ```--drmma``` option this error message shows up: ```RuleException in line 268 of phase.snakemake.py:
NameError: The name 'jobid' is unknown in this context. Please make sure that you defined that variable. Also note that braces not used for variable access have to be escaped by repeating them, i.e. {{print $1}}```